# Cannot draw TextButton or Button in LibGDX for desktop

Tags: opengl, libgdx, opengl-3, scene2d

I am trying to make a menu in LibGDX.
But I cannot get a Button or a textButton to get drawn in the screen.
I tried using the test skin. 
I tried to use a table.
I tried to use a button and a textbutton.

The image is fine because it can appears while drawing using the SpriteBatch and the font also works well.

This is part of my code.

```
public class Menu implements Screen {

    private Stage stage;
    private Skin skin;
    private TextButton textButton;
    private Game mygame;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private TextureRegion test;

    public SplashScreen(Game g){
        mygame = g; 
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.clear();
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("buttons/bot.pack");
        skin = new Skin(atlas);
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/arialfnt.fnt"),false);
        TextButtonStyle buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button.up");
        buttonStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("button.over");
        buttonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button.down");
        buttonStyle.font = font;

        textButton = new TextButton("Click here", buttonStyle);
        textButton.setPosition(200, 300);
        textButton.setHeight(300);
        textButton.setWidth(100); 

        test = atlas.findRegion("button.up"); //Testing the atlas
        stage.addActor(textButton);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw(); //DOES NOT WORK

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(test, 300, 300); //It works
        font.draw(batch, "BLA BLA!", 50, 500); //It works
        batch.end();

        }

}
```

Do you have any suggestion to make this work?
Can it be because of GL3.0?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but my best guess is you need to set the stage viewport. I can't look at my code or the libgdx source just yet but I will try to have a look when I get back home. Stage has it's own camera so I'm not sure how that's handled in its default constructor. Will check later.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Actually now it works. What I did is I create a completely new project. And paste my previous code. Now it works. It is very rare what happens. But anyone that needs how to make a new button in libgdx can use the code above it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the stage.draw() and batch draw thing and found out that for me in Android development, the following sequence works:

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(test, 300, 300); //It works
        font.draw(batch, "BLA BLA!", 50, 500); //It works
        batch.end();

        // Put stage.draw() after batch drawing!
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();

        }
```